# Identifying the product language for already installed application

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I have multilingual installation setup program, where user can select 5 different language. Consider I have installed application in German language. whenever I am uninstall the application or update the previous setup it is launching in German. I would like to know how setup will detect the older installation product language.

In my case I have created a upgrade only installation where it will detect the previous version of the installation and do the major upgrade. In the major upgrade I don't want to display the language dialog. The update should happen in the earlier installed lanugage.

Does installscript has any API to detect the earlier installed applications product language.?

I belive there should be some way to do like that as uninstallation does, Can any body give me some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure InstallScript installation, this is tracked in the uninstall key's command line. Look for the `/L` parameter.

For Windows Installer-based installations, this is remembered automatically by Windows Installer tracking which transforms are applied at initial installation. This includes the language transform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am using Basic MSI setup...How would I know which language is installed?

Comment: I'm not sure the best approach. Possibly using MsiGetProductInfo with one of the LANGUAGE related constants? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130.aspx Alternately you may have to open the package/product (so that the transform is applied) and read the summary information stream.